# In ssrs 2008 r2, how can i change the system generated "Please select a value for the parameter" error to "No active Products are available"

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset which returns nothing to a multi value parameter in few cases. When I click preview I get a pop up window stating "Please select a value for parameter" which is not user understandable. I want to convert this to a user understandable message.

Is there any option to change the system generated error messages?

Please someone help me on this issue.

Note: I handled this problem by passing a "" value in case of nothing (ie, when count = 0). The checkbox with blank value is visible. Is their any option to hide this checkbox or to change the system generated error.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: while creating paremeter u can check allow null

Comment: for a multi value u cannot allow null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a 'none' option to your multi-select options (possibly using UNION to add it to the dataset) and set this as the default.

Alternatively you could check the dataset before it is returned and if empty insert a the warning, such as "none available" in this set of returned values.

Then in the report check for your parameter equalling 'none' and if so show a text box with your error message on the report only. If 'none' is not selected then display the other report items as expected

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to show any values on parameter drop down.In this case none will be shown. If i try to replace none with "", i get empty drop down with check box. i don't want checkbox to be shown. Is their a way to hide checkbox ? or customize system generated error to my message ?

Comment: In short, no, I don't believe there is, hence the workaround suggested above